# R- collapse rows based on contents of two columns

Tags: mysql, arrays, r, data.table

I apologize in advance if this question is too specific or involved for this type of forum. I have been a long time lurker on this site, and this is the first time I haven't been able to solve my issue by looking at previous questions, so I finally decided to post.  Please let me know if there is a better place to post this, or if you have advice on making it more clear. here goes.

I have a data.table with the following structure:

```
library(data.table)
dt = structure(list(chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chrX",
"chrX", "chrX", "chrX"), start = c(842326, 855423, 855426, 855739,
153880833, 153880841, 154298086, 154298089), end = c(842327L,
855424L, 855427L, 855740L, 153880834L, 153880842L, 154298087L,
154298090L), meth.diff = c(9.35200555410902, 19.1839617944039,
29.6734426495636, -12.3375577709254, 50.5830043986142, 52.7503561092491,
46.5783738475184, 41.8662800742733), mean_KO = c(9.35200555410902,
19.1839617944039, 32.962962583692, 1.8512250859083, 51.2741224212646,
53.0928367727283, 47.4901932463221, 44.8441659366298), mean_WT = c(0,
0, 3.28951993412841, 14.1887828568337, 0.69111802265039, 0.34248066347919,
0.91181939880374, 2.97788586235646), coverage_KO = c(139L, 55L,
55L, 270L, 195L, 194L, 131L, 131L), coverage_WT = c(120L, 86L,
87L, 444L, 291L, 293L, 181L, 181L)), .Names = c("chr", "start",
"end", "meth.diff", "mean_KO", "mean_WT", "coverage_KO", "coverage_WT"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

These are genomic coordinates with associated values, the file is sorted by by chromosome ("chr") (1 through 22, then X, then Y), start and end position so that the first row contains the lowest numbered start position on chromosome 1, and proceeds sequentially for all data points on chromosome 1, then 2, etc.  At this point, every single row has a start-end length of 1.  After collapsing the start-end lengths will vary depending on how many rows were collapsed and their distance from the adjacent row.

**1st:** I would like to collapse **adjacent** rows into larger start/end ranges based on the following criteria:

1. The two adjacent rows share the same value for the "chr" column (row 1 "chr" = chr1, and row 2 "chr" = chr1)
2. The two adjacent rows have "start" coordinate within 500 of one another (if row 1 "start" = 1000, and row 2 "start" <= 1499, collapse these into a single row;  if row1 = 1000 and row2 = 1500, keep separate)
3. The adjacent rows must have the same sign for the "diff" column (i.e. even if chr = chr and start within 500, if diff1 = + 5 and diff2 = -5, keep entries separate)

**2nd:**  I would like to calculate the coverage_ weighted averages of the collapsed mean_KO/WT columns with the weighting by the coverage_KO/WT columns:

Ex: collapse 2 rows,

row 1 mean_1 = 5.0, coverage_1 = 20.

row 2 mean_1 =40.0, coverage_1 = 45.

weighted avg mean_1 = (((5.0*20)/(20+45)) + ((40.0*45)/(20+45))) = 29.23

What I would like the output to look like (except collapsed row means would be calculated and not in string form):

```
library(data.table)
dt_output = structure(list(chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chrX", "chrX"
), start = c(842326, 855423, 855739, 153880833, 154298086), end = c(842327, 
855427, 855740, 153880842, 154298090), mean_1 = c("9.35", "((19.18*55)/(55+55)) + ((32.96*55)/(55+55))", 
"1.85", "((51.27*195)/(195+194)) + ((53.09*194)/(195+194))", 
"((47.49*131)/(131+131)) + ((44.84*131)/(131+131))"), mean_2 = c("0", 
"((0.00*86)/(86+87)) + ((3.29*87)/(86+87))", "14.19", "((0.69*291)/(291+293)) + ((0.34*293)/(291+293))", 
"((0.91*181)/(181+181)) + ((2.98*181)/(181+181))")), .Names = c("chr", 
"start", "end", "mean_1", "mean_2"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Help with either part 1 or 2 or any advice is appreciated.

I have been using R for most of my data manipulations, but I am open to any language that can provide a solution.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going sleep now, but the following seems to be close what you are looking for: `dt[, .(mean_1 = list(mean_KO), mean_2 = list(mean_WT)), .(chr, start_grp = start %/% 500, end_grp = end %/% 500, diff_plus = meth.diff > 0)]`

Comment: Thanks A lot for your help! Sorry I had to step away to do some lab work, but I am in the process of updating the output and the question to make it more clear.  In the meantime I will also try out your code! Thanks again

Comment: I'd like to point out that there are two pairs of rows that satisfy the requirements in chrX in the example you provided. (And it appears that @Reilstein provided and effective solution, so I would encourage changing it to an 'answer'.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I changed the input example after jangorecki advised me, but I was working on changing the output.  Jangorecki's answer does not in fact give me the answer I am lookin for, although it is a step in the right direction, so I will clarify the input and output and ask again.

Comment: @jangorecki I tried your solution, and it was sort of similar to what I needed, except the "start" and "end" coordinates were not collapsed in the way I had wanted. The script changed the start and end coords and then rather than creating a start - end coordinate that encompassed both collapsed coordinates, it collapsed them into a single coordinate. For example, row 1 became chr 1 start=1684 end=1684, when it should have been chr1 start = 842326, end=842327.