# R - Compare rows of data.frame (to combine based on conditions)

Tags: r

I'm starting with a data.frame of genome ranges (a chromosome, and a start - end position).  I'm trying to combine rows that are 1) adjacently positioned and 2) that share a value in two other columns.  Note: I'd like an efficient method since my real data is > 10 million rows. (data.table if possible)

Toy data:

```
DF <- data.frame(SampleID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                 Chr = c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1),
                 Start = c(1, 101, 201, 401, 500, 1, 101),
                 End = c(100, 200, 300, 499, 599, 100, 200),
                 State = c(3,3,2,3,3,2,2)
                 )
DF
   SampleID Chr Start End State
1:        1   1     1 100     3
2:        1   1   101 200     3
3:        1   1   201 300     2
4:        1   1   401 499     3
5:        1   2   500 501     3
6:        2   1     1 100     2
7:        2   1   101 200     2
```

Lines 1 & 2 can be combined because they are adjacent (1-100 & 101-200) and share a `SampleID` (1) and `State` (3).

The following cannot be combined:

- Lines 2 & 3 have mismatched `State`s
- Lines 3 & 4 are not adjacent and do not share `State`
- Lines 4 & 5 differ in Chromosome (`Chr`)
- Lines 6 & 7 are a different `SampleID`.

Etcetera.  When we apply all these, we have this final table.

```
FinalDF <- data.frame(SampleID = c(1,1,1,1,2),
                      Chr = c(1,1,1,2,1),
                      Start = c(1,201,401,500,1),
                      End = c(200,300,499,599,200),
                      State = c(3,2,3,3,2))
FinalDF
  SampleID Chr Start End State
1        1   1     1 200     3
2        1   1   201 300     2
3        1   1   401 499     3
4        1   2   500 599     3
5        2   1     1 200     2
```

So, far, I've tried using the reduce function from the GenomicRanges package, but it doesn't work.

**INCORRECT OUTPUT**

```
reduce(DF2)
GRanges object with 3 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames     ranges strand
         <Rle>  <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]        1 [  1, 300]      *
  [2]        1 [401, 499]      *
  [3]        2 [500, 501]      *
  -------
  seqinfo: 2 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

I was trying to do something with data.table, since my data.frames are 10 million rows long or more, but haven't been able to figure it out.

The following question is along the same lines (maybe a bit more complex), but has no solution.
[R- collapse rows based on contents of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192216/r-collapse-rows-based-on-contents-of-two-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

dt = as.data.table(DF) # or convert in place using setDT

dt[, .(Start = min(Start), End = max(End), State = State[1])
   , by = .(SampleID, Chr, rleid(State),
            cumsum(c(FALSE, head(End + 1, -1) < tail(Start, -1))))]
#   SampleID Chr rleid cumsum Start End State
#1:        1   1     1      0     1 200     3
#2:        1   1     2      0   201 300     2
#3:        1   1     3      1   401 499     3
#4:        1   2     3      1   500 599     3
#5:        2   1     4      1     1 200     2
```

Comment: This works great, and very fast (0.51 seconds, I love data.table).  However, that I lose information in additional columns that I want to save. I assume I can just add them to the by statement (this changes the time to 0.61 seconds).  Is this the best way to handle this?

Comment: If you're grouping on those, yes, add to `by`; if you're not grouping on those, but they're the same for the already existing groups, you can instead just add first element similar to `State[1]` above

Answer (score 2):

If I interpret correctly what you want to do, I suggest the following: use `dplyr` to group by the metadata you want to keep separate and then use `GenomicRanges` to figure out the ranges within each group (if you run into performance issues you may want to steer clear of `data.frame` required for `GenomicRanges` and implement it by hand to take advantage of the performance of `dyplr` with data.tables). Here's an example of how this would work (making use of the pipe `%>%` to make it easier to see what's going on):

```
DF <- data.frame(SampleID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                 Chr = c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1),
                 Start = c(1, 101, 201, 401, 500, 1, 101),
                 End = c(100, 200, 300, 499, 599, 100, 200),
                 State = c(3,3,2,3,3,2,2)
)

library(dplyr)
# take your data frame
DF %>% 
  # group it by the subsets
  group_by(SampleID, Chr, State) %>% 
  # operate on each group
  do(
    # turn subset into a GRanges object
    as(as.data.frame(.), "GRanges") %>%
      # reducae ranges
      GenomicRanges::reduce() %>% 
      # turn back into data frame for dplyr to stitch together
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      # get the information you want
      select(start, end, width)
  ) %>% 
  # ungroup for future operations
  ungroup() %>% 
  # sort by what makes most sense for your set
  arrange(SampleID, Chr, start)
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 6]

SampleID Chr State start end width
(dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (int) (int) (int)
 1     1     3     1   200   200
 1     1     2   201   300   100
 1     1     3   401   499    99
 1     2     3   500   599   100
 2     1     2     1   200   200
```

Comment: This works great, except that I lose information (probably in the transfer between dataframe and GRanges object).  I have additional columns that I want to save.  I assume that I can add them to the group() statement, but that seems to slow it down considerably (63 seconds for my data using your code, 413 seconds after adding to the group statement).  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It depends what the additional columns contain. If this is additional information that has always the same value for each combination of the triplet (sampleId, Chr, State), I would use merge (or left_join in `dplyr`) at the end to bring it back in. If the additional columns can have variable values within each (sampleId, Chr, State) subset, you have to include in the group, otherwise, how would one know which one is the right value to use? (since the rows were collapsed).

Comment: ps: for the former case, this is how you could do it by adding to the end of your code (with another `%>%`):       `arrange(SampleID, Chr, start) %>% 
      left_join(
        distinct(select(DF, SampleID, Chr, State, info1, info2, info3)),
        by = c("SampleID", "Chr", "State")
      )`

Answer (score 1):

```
# This code is kind of robust but it appears to get the job done

DF <- data.frame(SampleID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                 Chr = c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1),
                 Start = c(1, 101, 201, 401, 500, 1, 101),
                 End = c(100, 200, 300, 499, 599, 100, 200),
                 State = c(3,3,2,3,3,2,2)
)

test_and_combine <- function(r1,r2) {
  if (r1[,1] == r2[,1] & # check if "SampleID" column matches
      r1[,2] == r2[,2] & # check if  "Chr" column matches
      (r1[,4] + 1) == r2[,3] & # test if Start and End are in sequence
      r1[,5] == r2[,5]) # check if "State"column matches
    {
    # merge rows if true
    DF_comb <- r1[,]
    DF_comb[1,4] <- r2[,4]

  }
  else{
    DF_comb <- NA 
  }
  return(DF_comb)
}

# This section could rewritten to use Reduce()
DF_comb_final <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(nrow(DF)-1)){ # loop through ever row of data.frame
  DF_temp <- test_and_combine(DF[i,],DF[i+1,]) # send two rows to function
  if(!any(is.na(DF_temp))){
    DF_comb_final <- rbind(DF_comb_final,DF_temp)    
  }
}
```